# Open specific screen of navigator from drawer

Tags: react-navigation

Following is my Drawer

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} initialParams={{ landingScreen: Home }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="A" component={AC} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="B" component={BC} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>
```

where the HomeStack is as following:

```
 <Stack.Navigator
      {<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />}
      <Stack.Screen name="Other1" component={OtherScreen1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Other2" component={OtherScreen2} />
 <Stack.Navigator/>
```

**Issue**

If I move to `OtherScreen2` and press *Home* from the Drawer, it opens the same screen instead of going to HomeScreen. How can I force Home to always go to root?